# How to show smooth transition in pageview if jumpTo function id used?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to change the current page upon click event using `jumpToPage()`.

But, it's changing it very abruptly without any animation.

The point of transition is that the user does not have to click next and plus if clicked on the wrong checkbox then he would know that if I scroll up I can change the option again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animateToPage:

> Animates the controlled PageView from the current page to the given page.
>
> The animation lasts for the given duration and follows the given curve. The returned Future resolves when the animation completes.

You have to provide a duration and a curve

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html

See all the curves animations here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html